# Scrapy Field Names that are not as per Python variable restrictions

Tags: python, variables, scrapy, naming-conventions

Is it possible to have field names that do not conform to python variable naming rules? To elaborate, is it possible to have the field name as "Job Title" instead of "job_title" in the export file. While may not be useful in JSON or XML exports, such an functionality might be useful while exporting in CSV format. For instance, if I need to use this data to import to another system which is already configured to accept CSVs with a certain field name.

Tried to reading the Item Pipelines documentation but it appears to be for an "an item has been scraped by a spider" but not for the field names themselves (Could be totally wrong though).

Any help in this direction would be really helpful!

Comment: Yes, it’s possible using dictionaries as items, since dictionaries allow arbitrary strings as keys. There is also a [feature request](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1008) to allow customizing the output field name, which you might want to watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a third party lib called `scrapy-jsonschema`. With that you can define your Items like this:

```
from scrapy_jsonschema.item import JsonSchemaItem

class MyItem(JsonSchemaItem):
    jsonschema = {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title": "MyItem",
        "description": "My Item with spaces",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "description": "The unique identifier for the employee",
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
                "description": "Name of the employee",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "job title": {
                "description": "The title of employee's job.",
                "type": "string",

            }
        },
        "required": ["id", "name", "job title"]
    }
```

And populate it like this:

```
item = MyItem()
item['job title'] = 'Boss'
```

You can read more about [here](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-jsonschema).

This solution address the Item definition as you asked, but you can achieve similar results **without defining an Item**. For example, you could just scrape the data into a dict and yield it back to scrapy.

```
yield {
    "id": response.xpath('...').get(),
    "name": response.xpath('...').get(),
    "job title": response.xpath('...').get(),
}
```

*with `scrapy crawl myspider -o file.csv` that would scrape into a csv and the columns will have the names you chose.*

You could also have the spider directly write into a csv, or it's pipeline, etc. Several ways to do it without a Item definition.

Comment: Thanks @renatodvc. This was useful. The "scrapy-jsonschema" works. And sorry for the late acknowledgement. :)